# HTML List-item spacing between number and text

Tags: html, text, html-lists, decimal, spacing

I need to increase the spacing between the decimal and the text of an ordered list, but I am using a DL instead of an OL element.

With the *margin-right* of the ::before element I can adjust the spacing.

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Blah blah blah</dt>
    <dd>Test test</dd>
    <dt>Blah blah blah</dt>
    <dd>Test test</dd>
    <dt>Blah blah blah</dt>
    <dd>Test test</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl {
    list-style: decimal inside;
}
dt {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
dt::before {
    display: list-item;
    content: ' ';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
dt:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle of what I tried. The spacing works, but the enumeration is not correct.
 **What am I doing wrong??**

http://jsfiddle.net/Fym2G/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could use a combination or of `content` `counter` and `counter-increment` and slap a margin on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/PR8Qd/

Answer (score 0):

Move `display:list-item` 
to 
`dt{ display:list-item}` It worked for me by changing your code. Here is the link to the edited code: http://jsfiddle.net/Fym2G/5/

Comment: Doing this, I can't add a margin to the _dt_ elements

Comment: What do you mean? Adding margin to the individual elements?